# Creating generic Signal using *args

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, signals, qobject

I'm trying to create a generic function caller class with the purpose of calling GUI functions from outside the main thread. The class has a signal and two functions: one is called to emit the signal and runs from a side thread. The other runs the actual function and is connected to the signal in the main thread.

In keeping this class generic, I want to be able to pass any number of arguments, as would normally be done using *args or **kwargs. But when initializing the Signal I'm required to define what arguments are passed.

This is my generic function caller (code stripped down for clarity):

```
from PySide.QtCore import Signal

class FunctionCaller(QObject):
    _request = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, function=str):
        super().__init__()
        self.function = function
        self._request.connect(self._do_function)

    @Slot(*args)
    def _do_function(self, *args):
        """This runs in the GUI thread to handle the thing."""
        self.function(*args)

    def doFunction(self, *args):        
        self._request.emit(*args)
```

Here's what appears in the main thread:

```
functionCaller = FunctionCaller(function = someGUIfunction)
foo = functionCaller.doFunction # foo is a global variable
```

And here's where I call the function in the side thread:

```
foo(0xc000, 'string')
```

The error I get when running the function with 3 arguments: `_request(int) only accepts 1 arguments, 3 given!`

Is there a way to do this or must this function be less generic than I hoped, only working for a set number and types of arguments?

Comment: What library does your Signal class belong to? You're passing an incorrect number of arguments somewhere else in the code that you haven't posted. Aside from the error you're receiving there also seems to be a flaw in the `_do_function` method since it will always be vulnerable to variable numbers of arguments. I'm not sure how your overall code is structured but would it be possible to combine a function and it's arguments with `functools.partial` and then just pass that down a queue to be called in the main thread/event loop?

Comment: @Sam It belongs to PySide.QtCore. I fixed some things and added relevant code that I missed, please take another look. I'm not sure how a partial function would work in this case. It doesn't get around the fact that I'm trying to pass any number of variables through a signal.